# Chrome Driver Timed out receiving message from renderer

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

In python 3.10.7 and using the latest stable versions of chrome and chrome driver, I get the following error:

> Message: timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 12.628
> (Session info: headless chrome=106.0.5249.91)

How can I increate the render timeout from 12.628 to something like 20?

Answer (score 1):

Changing the page_load_timeout length is quite easy with the `driver` instance:

```py
driver.set_page_load_timeout(20)
```

Comment: But I already have it, where REQUEST_TIMEOUT is 15 but yet it gives up on 12...

Comment: I can't see where you've defined ``REQUEST_TIMEOUT``. Is it possible that it's defined incorrectly?